# Add Icon with React native Material UI Button

Tags: react-native, material-ui

I have used the following Material UI for React Native

[React Native Material UI](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui)

From that library I have created Button with following code

```
<Button raised  upperCase={false} 
 text="Facebook"/>
```

The Button Created successfully.

Now i want to place the facebook icon before text facebook. As guided in the above library i have done that with following code

```
<Button raised  upperCase={false} icon="add-circle"  
     text="Facebook"/>
```

But there is no icon in that library named as 'fb' or 'facebook'.

So now i want to include facebook icon or my fb.png icon file in that button.

I am new to React Native app development. How can i do that using the same library?

If I am doing any thing wrong kindly guided me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but it might help someone. MaterialIcons doesn't have facebook icon, so you have to get the facebook icon with the following code

```
<Button
   large
   iconLeft
   fontWeight='bold'
   backgroundColor='#3b5998'
   icon={{name: 'facebook', type: 'font-awesome'}}
   title='Connect With Facebook' />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work. Is any packages import for that icons? because i got the warning as "Invalid prop icon supplied to button". Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. Try the above code with this https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements

Comment: Yes It's possible on react-native-elements. It would be good if this feature available on (https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui). Thanks @Jeffrey Rajan.